# Is WTL 10 compatible with Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c++, activex, atl, lnk2019, wtl

I am working on the creation of an ActiveX control using ATL/WTL on Visual Studio 2022, but when I try to compile my solution, I get the following errors:

> LNK2019   symbole externe non résolu __imp_GetOpenFileNameA référencé dans la fonction "public: **int64 **cdecl WTL::CFileDialogImpl::DoModal(struct HWND** *)" (?DoModal@?$CFileDialogImpl@VCFileDialog@WTL@@@WTL@@QEAA_JPEAUHWND**@@@Z)

> LNK2019   symbole externe non résolu __imp_GetSaveFileNameA référencé dans la fonction "public: **int64 **cdecl WTL::CFileDialogImpl::DoModal(struct HWND** *)" (?DoModal@?$CFileDialogImpl@VCFileDialog@WTL@@@WTL@@QEAA_JPEAUHWND**@@@Z)

I think it's probably **atldlgs.h** that makes everything go wrong, but I don't know why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Someone closed this question as "duplicate" and pointed out to this *very long* page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix
This is absolutely *not* beginner friendly. 
If this question is already answered in that long page thread, then please *clearly* point the OP to the *exact* answer in that long page. Or write a proper answer here.

Comment: Bottom of [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamea) shows the .lib file you have to link.  Project > Properties > Linker > Input > "Additional Dependencies" setting, add comdlg32.lib